# Inserting MATLAB files with a lot of lines

Tags: listings

I have a few MATLAB files with over 100 lines of code but when I use `\lstinputlisting`, I only get about the first 50 lines or so and it doesn't show up on the next page. Presumably, it's floating away somewhere on the same page. I've tried using `\afterpage`, `\clearpage`, `\cleardoublepage`, `\pagebreak`, and `\newpage`, but none of them help.

I'm a beginner with LaTeX and would appreciate any help that I can get.

Thanks!!

```
\lstset {language=Matlab,%  
    %basicstyle=\color{red},  
    breaklines=true,%  
    morekeywords={matlab2tikz},    
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},%  
    morekeywords=[2]{1}, keywordstyle=[2]{\color{black}},  
    identifierstyle=\color{black},%  
    stringstyle=\color{mylilas},  
    commentstyle=\color{mygreen},%  
    showstringspaces=false,  
    numbers=left,%  
    numberstyle={\tiny \color{black}},% size of the numbers  
    numbersep=9pt,  
     emph=[1]{for,end,break},emphstyle=[1]\color{red},    
    %emph=[2]{word1,word2}, emphstyle=[2]{style},      
}
```

Comment: Can you show the options you pass to `\lstinputlisting`? Are you using it in a `table` environment?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Have you by any chance added `float` as an option to the listings?

Comment: Can you post some code, so that we see which options you use, etc.

Comment: I don't think there is anything in the `\lstset` that would prevent page-breaking in a listing, so we need more information. Can you show us an example of how you add the `\lstinputlisting` as well? Ideally, create a complete, minimal example, starting with `\documentclass` ending with `\end{document}`, that demonstrates the problem. Remove everything that doesn't have any influence.

Comment: You might be interested in the [`matlab-prettifier`](https://bitbucket.org/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package; see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/158816/21891).